# .htaccess redirect for all sub-directories and files

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

We have a subsite a domain.com/path/ad and I want to diredirect all of the traffic to a framework handler. domain.com/path/index.cfm

So far I have

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.cfm [QSA,NS]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.cfm [R=permanent,L]
```

It correctly redirects /path/ad/other to /path/ad/index.cfm if the folder exists. What do I need to make it work for folders that do not exist? I will also need to keep track of the original file/path requested.

```
/path/ad/example1 => /path/ad/index.cfm?ad=example1
```

Answer (score 1):

In .htaccess under `/path`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^path/ad/(.+)$ path/index.cfm?ad=$1 [R=permanent,L]
</IfModule>
```

In the beginning of your question you wrote that you wanted to redirect to `path/index.cfm`, while at the end you wrote `path/ad/index.cfm` I'm assuming you intended the former.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to add an index.xxx (e.g. index.php if you use php) script. Apache will run /path/index.php with /ad/example1 in the environment variables if one tries to visit /path/ad/example1 and the /ad/example1 part doesn't exist (assuming that server is configured to use index.xxx for indexing, either globally or from .htaccess).

Since this is a script it can be made to do all kinds of redirects.

It's not the best solution since you'll have to maintain redirects in two locations but if you don't find another way then you may want to give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The whole point was to not have to maintain anything and let someone add whatever path they want for tracking purposes.